# Will defining the root password of Cloud SQL interfere with the connection of an application running on AppEngine?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I need to define the root password of my Google Cloud SQL instance to be able to connect using MySQL Workbench. Will defining the password interfere with the connection to the database of my AppEngine application? Or an application running from AppEngine have a different access than external tools?

The problem here is that the service must be always available and I am afraid of dropping my service for some time, while doing a deploy with the new Cloud SQL definitions, after changing the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about setting the root password using the Cloud SQL UI or `gcloud` command, it won't interfere.

That operation sets the password for `root@%` which includes every host *except* `locahost`. AppEngine uses the `root@localhost` user to connect to your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Exactly! Changing the root password in "Developers Console"->"Cloud SQL"->"Access Control".